# How do I see the beginners' grimoire after I have bought the more expensive one?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have already bought the more expensive one, but now I can't see the cheaper one. I need the teleporting spell to get stuff from chests in the hole.

Comment: I bought the expensive one first and I could buy the cheaper one later =/

Comment: When you say "see", do you mean in the Witch's hut or seeing the actual spells you get from it?

Comment: Screenshot may be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the actual book inside the Sorceress' hut, it's on the top shelf to the left of the book that has the number 666 on the bottom of it. If you can't actually find the book in that exact location, then it must be an in-game problem, so I suggest that you should contact aniwey (the developer) about this problem. You can find his email in the CFG  section of the game. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't put line breaks like that.